# What do I bind ajax success to to make my javascript work after a form submission replaces part of the DOM with a partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I render a page that has a partial named `_drills_dots` within it. The `drills.js.coffee` file contains one function that works until I load a form (via a partial), submit it (remote => true), and it loads the partial _drills_dots once again. Then the js funciton within drills.js.coffee no longer affects the freshly loaded div drawn by `_drills_dots` (clicking on the dots doesn't do what it's supposed to do).

**_drills_dots.html.erb:**

```
<div class='row drills dots' id='row_drill_dots'>
  <% @drills.each do |drill| %>
      <div class='small-9 columns unselected drill-object' id="<%= drill.id %>">
        <%= drill.name %>
      </div>
      <div class='small-3 columns'>
        <span class="unselected" id="dot-for-<%= drill.name %>"></span>
      </div>
      <hr>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class='small-12 columns', id='appended_drill_form'>
  <%= simple_form_for @drill, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="inputs">
      <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'ADD DRILL', label: false %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <div class='small-6 columns'>
        <%= f.button :submit, remote: true %>
      </div>
      <div class='small-6 columns text-right'>
        <%= link_to "Cancel", remove_drill_form_drills_path(params), remote: true, class: 'button' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<hr>
```

**drills.js.coffee**

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".drills > div > span").click ->
    $(this).toggleClass('unselected selected')
    $(this).parent().prev().toggleClass('unselected selected')
    . . .
```

***However***  if I remove the javascript from the `drills.js.coffee` file and put it inline within the partial, everything works.

The partial with the js inline (note it is now javascript here rather than coffeescript):

```
<div class='row drills dots' id='row_drill_dots'>
  <% @drills.each do |drill| %>
      <div class='small-9 columns unselected drill-object' id="<%= drill.id %>">
        <%= drill.name %>
      </div>
      <div class='small-3 columns'>
        <span class="unselected" id="dot-for-<%= drill.name %>"></span>
      </div>
      <hr>
  <% end %>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $(".drills > div > span").click(function() {
    var arrayOfIds, final, id, listOfIds, match, oldLink;
    $(this).toggleClass('unselected selected');
    $(this).parent().prev().toggleClass('unselected selected');
    id = $(this).parent().prev().attr('id');
    arrayOfIds = $.map($(".drill-object.selected"), function(n, i) {
      return "&amp;drill_ids%5B%5D=" + n.id;
    });
    listOfIds = "";
    arrayOfIds.forEach(function(id) {
      return listOfIds = listOfIds + id;
    });
    oldLink = $("#done-button").attr("href");
    console.log(oldLink);
    match = oldLink.match(/(?:group_id%5D=2)(.*)(?=&group=)/)[1];
    final = oldLink.replace(match, listOfIds);
    return $("#done-button").attr('href', final);
  });
});
</script>
```

I understand that there is some way to 'make things work' without moving the javascript into the partial and reloading it when I update the page.  I understand this has something to do with binding to ajax:success, I just don't know where to put it so that it actually does something for my situation.

I have tried putting it in my coffee script at: `$(".drills > div > span").bind("ajax:success").click ->`

Any tips?
but I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the partial are being loaded asynchronously.  If you include the JavaScript with the partial it is loaded every time and will work with the newly loaded drill dots.  The existing JavaScript will only bind to existing dots -- not those loaded asynchronously.

```
$(document).ready ->
    $(document).on "click", ".drills > div > span", ->
```